# How to downgrade visual studio 2019 for mac to version 8.4?

Tags: visual-studio-2019

I have  Visual Studio Community 2019 for Mac
Version 8.4.1 (build 4).
I need to downgrade to 8.4.
How I can do that?

Comment: Do you have any updates on this?

Answer (score 1):

I'm doing it, as everything got broken with the new version.

I found the old installers here (off-line)

https://mac.filehorse.com/download-visual-studio-community-mac/old-versions/

Im still solving the SDK stuff happening (thanks to the Frankenstain integration in the tool)

Some other references.
https://www.reddit.com/r/xamarindevelopers/comments/9wfgfs/downgrading_xamarinios_to_1012020/

From the source to check the correct version number:

https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/releases?after=xamarin-ios-14.17.2.4

Wish me luck

Comment: Done. It works, Check the OS version, VS Version, XCode Version, requirements, and them is you are dealing with Xamarin iOS development match the right version SDK from the developers with your requirements.

Comment: rather update the answer to give your feedback in the answer because comments are not permanent and might be removed